# Pulling item out of array using jquery in html

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

I am trying to set up a responsive slide show for my blog, and wanted to get it working using the Flickr api. I set up an array of the urls where my images are on flickr, but then I want to load them into the slide show dynamically. In responsiveSlides.js, when I load the image, it doesn't work and everything on the page renders terribly. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jquery</title> 

    $(function () {

      // Slideshow 1
      $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
        maxwidth: 800,
        speed: 800
      });

      // Slideshow 2
      $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        speed: 300,
        maxwidth: 540
      });

      // Slideshow 3
      $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
        manualControls: '#slider3-pager',
        maxwidth: 540
      });

      // Slideshow 4
      $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });

    var apiCall = "flickr json callback"; 
    var urls = new Array();


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(apiCall, function(data){

        $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, photo){
            var img_src = "http://farm" + photo.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_" + "s.jpg";
            urls.push(img_src);
        });
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>ResponsiveSlides.js</h1>



    <!-- Slideshow 1 -->

    <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
WHERE I WANT TO IMPORT THE IMAGE FROM THE ARRAY POPULATED IN JQUERY
      <li><img src="images/1.jpg" id="image" alt="nothing"></li>
     <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
        document.getElementById('image').src = urls.get(0);
     </script>
      <li><img src=urls[2] alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I guess my question is: when i have an html img src=x can x be pulled out of a jquery array and used as the source?

Comment: can u paste the link to your web page ?

Comment: @user1428716 its not published on my page yet, but here is what it is supposed to look: http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/

Comment: you dont have a start tag for the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also make sure that to check that your plugin function runs after $document.ready . (Of course $(document).ready() will run first).

Try this :

```
 $.getJSON(apiCall, function(data){

   $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, photo){//Populate your array});
    // Sanity : please check the size of array is equivalent to the number of  
    //the image tags in <li>
   $( "li img" ).each(function( index ) {
         $(this).attr('src', urls.pop());
    });


});
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you! I was going to add sanity check later, so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Since `urls` is an array so use `urls[index]` to retrieve the element from it. If you want get the item and at the same time remove as well then use `pop` method.

```
document.getElementById('image').src = urls.pop();
```

Comment: To elaborate on this, it would seem that after populating the `urls` array you would need to loop over it and add the `<img>` tags to the HTML...to construct the image tags you could use e.g. `$('<img/>', {src: urls[i]})` from within your loop.